# Finding a Python 2.7 -> 3.8 struct.Pack("H") into Strings for joining into Lists?

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion, byte

This is.. a **long** one. So I apologize for any inconsistency regarding code and problems. I'll be sure to try and add as much of the source code as I can to make sure the issue is as clear as possible.

This project at work is an attempt at converting Python 2 to 3, and thus far has been mildly straightforward. My coworker and I have reached a point though where no amount of googling or searching has given a straight answer, so here we are.

---

Alright, Starting offwith...

## Python 2 code:

```py
listBytes[102:104]=struct.pack('H',rotation_deg*100) # rotational position in degrees
listBytes[202:204]=struct.pack('H',rotation_deg*100) # rotational position in degrees
listBytes[302:304]=struct.pack('H',rotation_deg*100) # rotational position in degrees
# this continues on for a while in the same fashion
```

Where rotation_deg is a float between 0.00 and 359.99 (but for testing is almost always changing between 150-250)

For the purpose of testing, we're going to make rotation_deg be 150.00 all the time.

```py
a = listBytes[102:104]=struct.pack('H',150.00*100)
print a
print type(a)
```

The print out of the following is:

```
�:
<type 'str'>
```

From what I understand, in the Python2 version of struct.pack, it is packing the floats as shorts, which then are "added" to the list as a short. Python 2 sees it as a string, and adds no encoding to the string  (will get to that later for python 3). All simple and good, then a few more bits and bobs of dropping more stuff into the list and we get to:

```py
return ''.join(listBytes)
```

Which, is being sent back to a simple variable:

```py
bytes=self.UpdatePacket(bytes,statusIndex,rotation_deg,StatusIdList,StatusValueList, Stat,offsetUTC)
```

To then be sent along as a string through

```py
sock.sendto(bytes , (host, port) )
```

This all comes together to look like this:
[A string with a bunch of bytes (I think)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLuAS.png)

****This is the working version****, in which we are sending the bytes along the socket, data is being retrieved, and everyone is happy. If I missed anything, please let me know, otherwise, lets move to...

---

## Python 3

[This is where the Fun Begins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOft0.gif)

There are a few changes that are required between Python 2 and 3 right off the bat.

1. `struct.pack('H',rotation_deg*100)` requires an INT type to be packed, meaning all instances of packing had to be given `int(rotatin_deg*100)` as to not error the program.
2. `sock.sendto(bytes, (host, port))` did not work anymore as the socket needed a bytes object to send something. No more strings that look like bytes, they had to be properly encoded to send properly. So now this becomes `sock.sendto(bytes.encode(), (host, port))` to properly encode the "bytes" string.

As more of a background, the length of **listBytes** should always be **1206**. Anymore and our socket won't work properly, and the issue is that no matter what we try with this python 3 code, the **.join** seems to be sending a LOT more than just byte objects, often quintupling the length of **listBytes** and breaking the socket.sendto .

```py
listBytes[102:104] = struct.pack('H', int(rotation_deg * 100))  # rotational position in degrees
listBytes[202:204] = struct.pack('H', int(rotation_deg * 100))  # rotational position in degrees
listBytes[302:304] = struct.pack('H', int(rotation_deg * 100))  # rotational position in degrees
# continues on in this fashion again
```

```py
return ''.join(str(listBytes))
```

returns to:

```py
bytes = self.UpdatePacket(bytes, statusIndex, rotation_deg, StatusIdList, StatusValueList, Stat, offsetUTC)
sock.sendto(bytes.encode(), (host, port))
```

**Here's where things start getting weird**

```py
a = struct.pack('H', int(150.00 * 100))
```

returns:
`b'\x98:'`, with it's type being `<class 'bytes'>`, which is fine and the value we want, except we specifically need to store this variable into the list as maybe a string... to encode it later to send as a byte object for the socket.

You're starting to see the problem, yes?

The thing is, we've tried just about every technique to convert the two bytes that struct.pack returns into a string of some kind, and we've been able to convert it over, but then we run into the issue of the **.join** being evil.

Remember when I was talking about **listBytes** had to remain a size of 1206 or else it would break? For some reason, if we **.join** literally anything other than the two bytes as a string, we think python is trying to add a bunch of other stuff that we don't need.

So for now, we're focusing on trying to match the python 2 equivalent to python 3.

**Here's what we've tried**

`binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('H', int(150.00 * 100))).decode()` returns `'983a'`

`str(struct.pack('H', int(150.00 * 100.00)).decode())` returns an error, `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 0: invalid start byte`

`str(struct.pack('H', int(150.00 * 100.00)).decode("utf-16"))` returns `'㪘'`. Can't even begin to understand that.

`return b''.join(listBytes)` returns an error because there are int's at the start of the list.

`return ''.join(str(listBytes)).encode('utf-8')` still is adding a bunch of nonsense.

---

Now we get to the **.join**, and the first loop around it seems.. fine? It has 1206 as **listBytes** length before .joining, but on the second loop around, it creates a massive influx of junk, making the list **5503** in length. Third go around it becomes **27487**, and finally on the last go around, it becomes to large for the socket to handle and I get slapped with `[WinError 10040] A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself`

---

Phew, **if you made it this far**, thank you. Any help at all would be extremely appreciated. If you have questions or I'm missing something, let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You’re just trying too hard.  It may be helpful to think of `bytes` and `unicode` rather than the ambiguous `str` type (which is the former in Python 2 and the latter in Python 3).  `struct` **always** produces `bytes`, and `socket` needs to send `bytes`, regardless of the language version.  Put differently, everything **outside** your process is bytes, although some represent characters in some encoding chosen by the rest of the system.  Characters are a data type used to manipulate text **within** your program, just like floats are a data type used to manipulate “real numbers”.  You have no characters here, so you definitely don’t need `encode`.

So just accumulate your `bytes` objects and then join them with **`b''.join`** (if you can’t just directly use the buffer into which your slice assignments seem to be writing) to keep them as bytes.

Comment: Seems the listBytes has int objects at the start, so b''.join won't convert those. 

return ''.join(str(listBytes)).encode('utf-8') was a work around, but it's still causing the .join to pile in massive amounts of random junk.

Comment: Coming back to this, I figured out the fix. 

```return bytes(listBytes)``` seems to fix all the issues I was having. Thanks for the push in the right direction!